# Register c# Lib as Assembly in USQL solution project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I created USQL project in visual studio. I created job and it executed successfully. While following demos, I have added one separate c# lib in solution. But when I tried to register lib as assembly, I could not able to find it on right click in context menu.

My environment:

> windows 10 Visual Studio-2015

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a .NET library project if you choose the project type "Class Library (For U-SQL Application)" from the New Project dialog, then you will get a project that knows about ADL. You can do this for a brand new solution, or when you add a project to an existing solution. In that case you will get the context menu where the project is listed in the Solution Explorer for registering the library.

For registering *any* library, you can kick off the process by going to the Server/Cloud Explorer and navigating to the Data Lake Analytics account you want to use. There you can expand the "U-SQL databases" node, and then the particular database you want (e.g. master). You will see an Assemblies listing. You can right-click on this part of the tree and you'll get the register assembly option which will walk you thru the steps needed.

Comment: thanks, but while trying to register assembly, still not able to submit due to Input status : Not ready to submit registration. what should i do here?

Comment: Did you make sure that you have the latest version of the tool? There was an issue with registering assemblies in one release that got fixed.